# Canceled WCF REST downloads

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a REST service that returns large files via a Stream as the return type.  However I need a way to know how much of the file was transferred even if the download is canceled by the client.  What would be the best way to accomplish something like this?

So far I've come up with the following:

```
        public Message GetFile(string path)
    {
        UsageLog log = new UsageLog();

        return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateStreamResponse((stream) =>
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[_BufferSize];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                long totalBytesRead = 0;

                while (true)
                {
                    bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, _BufferSize);

                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    catch (CommunicationException ex)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                }

                log.TransferCompletedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                log.BytesTransferred = totalBytesRead;
            }
        },
        "application/octet-stream");
    }
```

I'm interested in hearing any other solutions to accomplishing something like this.

Comment: how you client is accessing the service? can you show some code?

Comment: Currently I'm testing it with a demo client written in .NET that uses HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse to perform the downloads but that shouldn't matter because the REST service is designed for any type of client.